Kafka not recognizing key
I'm trying to set SSL in a broker that I'm running locally for testing setting this up. This broker will be running with Kraft, and SSL will be set up using PEMs (not keystores or truststores).
I've created the private key, certificates, got them all signed and whatnot, but when starting Kafka, I'm getting the following error:
[2024-12-11 18:18:37,997] ERROR [BrokerServer id=1] Fatal error during broker startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.BrokerServer)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: Invalid PEM keystore configs
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: No matching PRIVATE KEY entries in PEM file

This is SSL part in the config file:
# Private key (your server's private key)
ssl.keystore.type=PEM
ssl.keystore.key=/home/sedulam/IT/kafka/security/server-key.pem

# Certificate chain (server public certificate)
ssl.keystore.certificate.chain=/home/sedulam/IT/kafka/security/server-cert.pem

# Path to the truststore containing the CA cert
ssl.truststore.type=PEM
ssl.truststore.certificates=/home/sedulam/IT/kafka/security/cacert-exported.pem

ssl.client.auth=required

Comparing the private key with the one on the certificate, seems to indicate it's correct:
$ openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in server-key.pem | openssl md5
(stdin)= 17a5e95b10568c22f2195594ec2292d0
$ openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in server-cert.pem | openssl md5
(stdin)= 17a5e95b10568c22f2195594ec2292d0

I've followed the steps from the official documentation. Using Kafka v3.1. What am I doing wrong?
